# pi Approximation quiz in psyschool.com

Tags: python-3.x

I've writen this code for this quiz:

"Create a function that computes the approximation of pi, based on the number of iterations specified."
pi can be computed by 4*(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9- ...).

it gives me correct answers in pycharm. but when I run it in the website it gives me wrong answers. what should I do?
thanks

```
def piApprox(num):
    i = 1
    pi = 0
    while i <= num:
        a = (4/((2*i)-1))*((-1)**(i-1))
        pi += a
        print(pi)
        i += 1  
    return round(pi, 11)
```

correct answers:.................my answers:

3.13959265559...................3.0

4.0.......................................4.0

3.04183961893...................3.0

3.25236593472...................3.0

Comment: What are your input values for `num` and what are you expected values for pi?

Comment: After testing against your input cases, your code produces your desired result? Can you provide a case with an issue?

Comment: Python gives me desired results. but this website (http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s5-q10) gives the wrong answers

Comment: There's not much SO can help with since your example can be verified as working, and your issue is not duplicatable in all environments. It must be something on their end or a certain constraint in the instructions.

Comment: Where are these answers being displayed?

Comment: You could try to change to 'pi = 0.0' first, looks like a float/int problem.

Comment: When I run the code in this website (pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s5-q10) these answers are displayed.

Comment: I tried  'pi = 0.0' but the problem didn't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like the round function isn't working as expected. Maybe just remove it so

```
    return pi
```

and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, I got it this time. You got the order wrong. By multiplying at the end and tweakin some other stuff you should arrive at a solution close to this `def piApprox(num):
    pi=4.0
    i=1.0
    est=1.0
    while 1<num:
        i+=2
        est=est-(1/i)+1/(i+2)
        num=num-1
        i+=2
    return round(pi*est, 11)`

Comment: Your code answers are:  3.14259365434...............4.0................3.19418790923...................3.20036551541

Comment: Teste cases are: num = 500 ,num = 1 ,num = 10 and num = 9